# Message Sequence Charts with timeline and analysis

Tags: charts, uml, sequence, message

I am looking for a visualization tool that can parse a log and display a message sequence chart with time line view. Below is an example:

```
2016-02-18 01:01:012345 [B] Send Message to A
2016-02-18 01:01:123456 [A] Received Message from B
2016-02-18 01:01:234567 [A] Some Custom Message
2016-02-18 01:01:567890 [B] This is some other custom message
```

I would like to view this in the following format:

[image]

The red ovals correspond to custom images.

Can you please suggest any open source tool that can parse the log and visualize the sequences.

It would be great if the tool can accept some predefined sequences and then detect those sequence violations in the log.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend something are off topic here. Honestly, I can't understand why those are up-voted.